# Strongly typed enums without explicit scoping?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

I want strong enum types. C++0x has this feature but unfortunately they also require explicit scoping:

```
enum class E {e1, e2, e3};
E x = E::e1; //OK
E y = e1; //error
```

Sometimes this is desirable, but sometimes it's just unnecessarily verbose. The identifiers might be unique enough by themselves or the enum might already be nested inside a class or namespace.

So I'm looking for a workaround. What would be the best way to declare the enum values also in the surrounding scope?

Comment: +1 "Thanks, me too". Been annoyed by the same thing ever since strongly typed enums came out, to an extent that I'm not using them. It's beyond me why there is no such thing as `using` for `enum`s either. While `using` is being overused by a lot of people, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: If your scoped enums are enclosed in a class or namespace, you're forcing yourself to be verbose. Move the enums outside of them, that's what they're for!

Comment: @rubenvb: `enum class` have nothing to do with classes.

Comment: phresnel: I am aware of that, but the OP said: `or the enum might already be nested inside a class or namespace`. I simply suggested removing that extra syntactical indirection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the values visible in the surrounding scope, just add a couple of constants:

```
enum class E {e1, e2, e3};

const E e1 = E::e1;
const E e2 = E::e2;
const E e3 = E::e3;
```

Comment: The difference is that the values are not implicitly convertible to integer types. Can save us some bugs.